# Response.entity returns NULL , instead it should return JSON RESPONSE

Tags: json, rest, jax-rs

I am trying out hard to get that why the response .entity returns null but still not getting the answer what to do with it
in other examples i tried it returns the response but over here m not getting why null being received in the response
please help me out with the same

```
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response.Status;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.ExceptionMapper;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;

import com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors;

@Provider
public class GenericExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<Throwable> {

    @Override
    public Response toResponse(Throwable ex) {

        ErrorMessage errorMessage = new ErrorMessage();
        errorMessage.setStatus(404);
        errorMessage.setMessage(ex.getMessage());
        return Response.status(Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
                .entity(errorMessage).type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE)
                .build();
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you tried the same in rest client?

Comment: Are you sure the mapper is even being called?

Comment: and yes when i am passing the string it returns the correct response .. i,e Response.entity(ex.getMessage) .. but on Response.entity(errorMessage).. the response returned is nul :(